# msg=Multiple values encountered for non multiValued copy field

Tags: python, apache, solr, solr4

I have dictionary with updated values and i want to update the field value(s) with the dynamic values in solr using python code. for example i have shown `retweet_count` this field is dynamic evertime it gets changed.

it should not be a multivalued field.

code:

```
                    try:
                        if res['retweet_count'] != tweets['retweet_count']:
                            print "retweet increased  . . old retweets : ", res['retweet_count'], " new retweets : ", tweets['retweet_count']
                            res['retweet_count'] = tweets['retweet_count']
                    except KeyError:
                        print "retweet_count not in res"
                        res['retweet_count'] = tweets['retweet_count']
                    solr.add([res])
```

error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "user.py", line 267, in <module>
        get_all_tweets(x)
      File "user.py", line 245, in get_all_tweets
        solr.add({'set':[res]})  # ==> solr
      File "/home//anaconda3/envs/TwitterINt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 1050, in add
        solrapi=solrapi,
      File "/home//anaconda3/envs/TwitterINt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 572, in _update
        {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
      File "/home//anaconda3/envs/TwitterINt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 463, in _send_request
        raise SolrError(error_message % (resp.status_code, solr_message))
    pysolr.SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: ERROR: [doc=1059346579209936896] Error adding field 'retweet_count'='0' msg=Multiple values encountered for non multiValued copy field retweeted_count: 0]
```

Comment: you need to define retweeted_count field as multiValued="true"... as this fields is copy field and will hold values of other multiple fields

Comment: if you could share the schema defined ...would be better

Comment: yeah but i dont want it to be multivalued ! suppose retweeted_count = 5 after sometimes it will be retweeted_count = 10 so it should update . Schema -   <field name="retweet_count" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

Comment: is the field name="retweet_count" a copy field?

Comment: are you passing the array values to it?

Comment: yes field name="retweet_count" is a copy field. and passing dictionary values

Comment: Why do you need it as copy field? Are you pushing multiple fields data to it?

Comment: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/copying-fields.html

Comment: used copy field because i want to copy field from one to another.

Comment: then you need to define it as multivalued as true...or if you your field is holding single value then you can create another field and apply the required fieldType to it

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the field `retweet_count` in `schema.xml` as `multiValued="true"`.

This would help you to resolve your error.

your field definition would be something like below.

```
<field name="retweet_count" type="mention_the_field_type" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true" />
```